# php опитимизация не могу понять почему код работает 2 секунды

Tags: php, pdo

`

```
$start = microtime(true); $DBHOST = 'localhost'; 
 $DBNAME = 'test'; 
 $DBUSER = 'root' ; 
 $DBPASS = '123';


 $dbc = new PDO("mysql:host=". $DBHOST .";dbname=".
                          $DBNAME, $DBUSER, $DBPASS);


    $sql = 'SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = :email';
    $email = 'asd@mail.ru';
    $result = $dbc->prepare($sql);
    $result->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $result->execute();
    $user = $result->fetch();
    if($user){

    } 

    echo 'Время выполнения скрипта: '.round(microtime(true) - $start, 4).' сек.'`
```

Comment: сложный вопрос. если удалить соединение с бд, он должен выдать ошибку мгновенно

Comment: комментирую строку `
    $db = Db::getConnection();`

Comment: знчит дело в чем-то ещё. мы не знаем, в чем

Comment: Вот этот код срабатывает за 2 секунды

Comment: замени localhost на 127.0.0.1

Comment: Заработало но я не понял почему можете объяснить?

Comment: ДНС тупит. можно погуглить, проблема частая

Comment: Ответьте пожалуйста ответом

Comment: Чтобы написать релевантный ответ, то нужен релевантный вопрос. вопрос с заголовком "почему код работает 2 секунды" приведет кого угодно, но не человека с такой же проблемой